# Computing binomial coefficients and factorials modulo a composite number

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Does anyone know of a fast algorithm to compute factorials and/or binomial coefficients in general or modulo a composite number in particular (for composite moduli I am interested in the case where the factorization is not necessarily known)  I know that for primes and factorials we can apply Wilson's Theorem but I was wondering if there is also a fast method for composite numbers.  For binomial coefficients I was thinking of using recursion and the addition rule: $$\binom{n}{x} + \binom{n}{x+1} = \binom{n+1}{x+1}$$ somehow but I'm not sure really how to go about it.  Any suggessions?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the factorization of the modulus?  Please edit the question to specify, as that makes a tremendous difference to the best answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p$ is prime and $n = n_\ell \ldots n_0$, $x = x_\ell \ldots x_0$ in base $p$, [then (Lucas' theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem)
$$ \binom{n}{x} \equiv \binom{n_\ell}{x_\ell} \cdots \binom{n_0}{x_0} \pmod{p}. $$

For a product of distinct primes, you can apply the Chinese remainder theorem. So it remains to deal with prime powers. Such a method is described in [this paper](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf) of Andrew Granville, though it's not as nice as the formula above.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there another efficient method if the factorization of the modulus is not initially known?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of.

Comment: I implemented Andrew Granville's algorithm here : https://github.com/elaqqad/HackerRank/blob/master/nCr_moduloMComposite.py